# How many CPU and Ram Jmeter uses

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I should test 5 API endpoints with 100000 concurrent users. So I read best practices as well as  Jmeter documentation it self. I am aware of AWS machines. right. now I am suffering for finding the documentation for machine resource Jmeter use. I mean How can I calculate how many cpu and Ram does jmeter uses per 1k thread? in general please help me to find solution out.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to find any "documentation" on this because JMeter's resources consumption strongly depends on the nature of your test:

- size of request and response
- number of [post-processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and [assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions)
- presence of [timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)
- etc.

and these parameters differ from test to test, 1k users which send simple [HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request and receiving small response will consume much less resources than 1k users which are uploading large files and receive huge responses.

So you need to:

1. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. Set up monitoring of JMeter resources consumption in terms of CPU, RAM, Network and Disk IO, etc. You can use i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) for this if there are no better options
3. Start with 1 user and gradually increase the load at the same time looking at resources consumption
4. When any of monitored metrics starts exceeding i.e. 80% of maximum available capacity - see how many threads were active at this moment
5. This is how many threads you can simulate **for particular this test from particular this machine**. Divide 100000 by that number and you will get the number of JMeter engines you need to set up for conducting your load.